# Filtering results for date but getting system.type error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to filter certificates on my local machine and remove all created before 4/10/2021

```
PS C:\Users\juraj> $cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\localMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.NotBefore -is [DateTime]::Today  }
Cannot convert value "14/10/2021 12:00:00 AM" to type "System.Type". Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.DateTime' to
'System.Type'."
At line:1 char:62
+ ... ocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.NotBefore -is [DateTime]::Today  }
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

So currently I'm testing the function but even when converted (Get-Date).ToString it ends with similar red sea of errors.

How do I go about this?

PS 5.1 in W11

Comment: is there anything in the `Cert:\LocalMachine\My` path? my system shows nothing there.

Comment: yes, we do have items there.. for testing, you can use root cert path Cert:\LocalMachine\CA

Comment: ok ... that gives me an object. now ... **_WHY are you testing to see if the two objects are the same type?_** and why are you testing the result of the static method instead of just the type? using `[datetime]` instead of `[datetime]::today()` works without any errors ... [*grin*]

Comment: doesn't seem to be working for me though 
PS C:\Users\juraj> Get-ChildItem Cert:\localMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.NotBefore -is [DateTime]::Today()  }
Method invocation failed because [System.DateTime] does not contain a method named 'Today'.

Comment: REMOVE the silly static method from your `[datetime]` section. _just use the type ... the `-is` operator checks a TYPE, not a static method. [*grin*]

Comment: can you put the full command in as without the '-is' operator it's still not working for me. Not sure what I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out - I converted string into [datetime] and then use it as a filter

```
$string='13/10/2021'
$string=[Datetime]::ParseExact($string, 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null)
Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\localMachine\My | Where { $_.NotBefore -lt $string  } | Remove-Item
```

Comment: excellent! [*grin*] that not only _works_ ... it makes your intent clear. the other code was using `-is` in ways that made the intent unclear to me.